# ikfast for selfmade arm

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, ikfast

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It said *>5 points required to upload a picture*, so I have to draw my robot arm here.

```
   |  |
   |  |   ---> joint4  y axis rotate
   |  |
   |  |   ---> joint3   y axis rotate
   |  |
   |  |   ---> joint2   y axis rotate
+ - - - - +
|         |  ---> joint1  z axis rotate
+ - - - - +
```

Hope it is clear!
As you can see this robot arm DOF is 4, so moveit kdl can't work well with it,
and I can't move the interactive marker in rviz.

So I try to use ikfast to solve this problem.
Actually, I don't know which IK type is suitable for this case, so I tried TranslationX(Y/Z)AxisAngle4D.

But without luck, after I configure the moveit plugin successfully, still I can't move interactive mark.
My question is what type of IK should I use? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385695/ikfast-for-selfmade-arm/) by [peng cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/74946/peng-cheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2021-09-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2021-09-04**:
Might be similar to the default [open manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/question/366152/openmanipulator-with-moveit/)  configuration. Did openrave have a valid solution for any of the Translation*AxisAngle4D?  Did the test succeed?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2021-09-04**:
Btw you should now have some points ;)

**Comment by [peng cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/74946/peng-cheng/) on 2021-09-04**:
@Humpelstilzchen,
If I am correct, the open manipulator doesn't have joint1 which can rotate around the z-axis.
Yes, for all 3 Translation*AxisAngle4D, the test are success with such output,

```
openravepy.databases.inversekinematics: testik, success rate: 0.989000, wrong solutions: 0.000000, no solutions: 0.011000, missing solution: 0.022000
```

**Comment by [peng cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/74946/peng-cheng/) on 2021-09-04**:
@Humpelstilzchen, Sorry, I don't understand "have some points",

I have four files available in the output directory:

```
ikfast0x10000049.TranslationZAxisAngle4D.0_1_2_3.cpp  ikfast0x10000049.TranslationZAxisAngle4D.0_1_2_3.pp  ikfast0x10000049.TranslationZAxisAngle4D.x86_64.0_1_2_3.so  ikfast.h
```

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2021-09-04**:
points on answers.ros.org. The first axis on openmanipulator is rotating about upwards axis which is z in my coordinate system. Does your generated *ikfast_moveit_plugin.cpp have code in "case IKP_TranslationZAxisAngle4D"? (also X any Y)

**Comment by [peng cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/74946/peng-cheng/) on 2021-09-04**:
@Humpelstilzchen, apologize, you are correct, the first joint of the open manipulator is rotating about the z-axis.
Yes, it has such case, and I also cherry-picked this [MR](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/1823/files), so it loos like this for Y Axis case:

```
    case IKP_TranslationYAxisAngle4D:
case IKP_TranslationYAxisAngleXNorm4D:
  // For **TranslationYAxisAngleXNorm4D** - end effector origin reaches desired 3D translation, manipulator
  // direction needs to be orthogonal to x axis and be rotated at a certain angle starting from the y axis (defined
  // in the manipulator base link’s coordinate system)
  pose_frame.M.GetRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
  ComputeIk(trans, &roll, vfree.size() > 0 ? &vfree[0] : NULL, solutions);
  return solutions.GetNumSolutions();
```

**Comment by [The Red Star](https://answers.ros.org/users/89379/the-red-star/) on 2021-11-11**:
Hi，I am using iktype=translationxaxisangle4d，but I always get the error：CannotSolveError（some equations are not consistent with the ik，double check if using correct IK type），do you know why，my friend

**Comment by [The Red Star](https://answers.ros.org/users/89379/the-red-star/) on 2021-11-11**:
Can I use your description of the arm to raise a new question?
|  |
|  |   ---> joint4  y axis rotate
|  |
|  |   ---> joint3   y axis rotate
|  |
|  |   ---> joint2   y axis rotate

- - - - - - 

|         |  ---> joint1  z axis rotate

- - - - - - 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Find the cause, I set the wrong first joint, I guess ikfast expects the first joint to be the one rotating about the z-axis, but I added one more fixed joint which connects to the world, ikfast works after removing it.

---

Originally posted by [peng cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/74946/peng-cheng/) with karma: 36 on 2021-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1